# How do I change the Button background using Behaviors?

Tags: behavior, winui-3

```
<Button Height="50" BorderBrush="IndianRed" Margin="5,0,0,0"
    x:Name="aBtn">
    <Button.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="IndianRed"/>
    </Button.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <TextBlock Text="Heating" />
    </StackPanel>
    <iActivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <iAction:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="IndianRed" TargetObject="aBtn" />
    </iActivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This doesn't work. (I'm using WinUI3 Preview 4)

Answer (score 0):

`TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=aBtn}"` is needed.